# Convert a uint8_t array of values to their hex equivalents in a char array

Tags: c, arrays, hex, data-conversion

`char readBuf[] = "96 36 D4 D1 F8 C1 8A E0 BF 29 10 91 3C 4D F1 5D 08";`

I would like to translate each pair of values into a hex value so that I have 17 separate hex values in a new char[].

The result would be equivalent to writing this in code:

`char hexStr[] = {0x96, 0x36, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xF8, 0xC1, 0x8A, 0xE0, 0xBF, 0x29, 0x10, 0x91, 0x3C, 0x4D, 0xF1, 0x5D, 0x08}`

I don't know how to construct a new hex value from the readBuf to add it to a new char[].

Comment: Your results don't make sense to me. readBuf[1] is a '6' and maps to 0x36 in asciiStr, but readBuf[4] is also a '6' and maps to 0xF8. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've updated to hopefully make it clearer and deleting that last comment which confuses things!

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
char readBuf[] = "96 36 D4 D1 F8 C1 8A E0 BF 29 10 91 3C 4D F1 5D 08";
size_t length = strlen(readBuf);
// ideally the length of this should be computed from the string length and allocated dynamically
uint8_t result[17]; 
size_t pos = 0;
while(pos * 3 < length) {
    int value;
    int scanned = sscanf(readBuf + pos * 3, "%x", &value);
    if(scanned == 1) {
        result[pos] = value;
        pos ++;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid hex number at %zu", pos * 3);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is a lot more compact and removes the need to use the hex to int method. It also includes error handling for the invalid hex numbers. As a result, I have updated the correct answer to this. If anyone can see a reason why this shouldn't be the accepted answer, please chip in.